# Gradle Sync failed while using proxy server

Tags: proxy, gradle, android-studio

I have installed Android studio and i want to build first app. Unfortunately "Gradle project sync failed" Error: Connection refused: connect.

I know it's because i use proxy server (my company does). I already made changes in Setings->HTTP Proxy-> Auto-detect proxy settings, but I guess, Gradle doesn't look on it. I read I should make write in gradle.properties my proxy server, user and password, but I don't know this parameters, and i don't know how to get them (even if it is available or not).

Can you help me? there are two ways: 1. If you know tell me how to avoid this problem without that parameters. For example like Auto-detect 2. How to get those parameters?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Apparently this code works

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=<hostname>
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=localhost
```

or for `https`

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=<hostname>
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=localhost
```

when password isn't set up.
It should be in gradle.properties file.

Comment: Thanks! This really solves my problem. Just add all the items for both "http" and "https", just leave it blank if there's any value any of the item and place the "gradle.properties" (C:\Users\HOME-USER\.gradle) or (C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle). If "gradle.properties" don't exists, just create one.

Comment: Thanks! You've saved my day ^^

Comment: Thanks. Adding https.proxyPort and proxyHost solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Enable **No Proxy** from **Appearance and Behavior** -> **System Settings**-> HTTP Proxy -> NO Proxy

This is worked for me

[image]